# Migrate users account from Joomla 3 to another Joomla 3 manually

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate Joomla 3 user's information to another Joomla 3 installation.

From PHPMyAdmin I exported _users table and _user_usergroup_map to the new Database. There actually appear on the user administrator sections, but when I'm trying to log in using my credentials it say that password is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?. There is some step that am I missing?.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the server you migrated to running the minimum PHP version required? Please remember you can ask your Joomla related questions over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), where it will most likely get more attention ;)

Comment: How do the password strings of users in the origin and destination table? Are they equals? What about your old and new DB encoding?

Comment: The password hash are the same, but how there are different installations of joomla i don't know if there suppose to be different hash even if the string of the password is the same...